# JQuery - Hide Div when p is empty with multiple instances

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hide

I'm trying to hide a div when the user doesn't enter text into a p field within that div - I can do this using :empty easily enough but the page has multiple instances of the same div so it hides them all if just one of the p is empty - I think I can fix this using an 'else' but can't get it to work...

My markup:

```
<div class="sticker"><a href="#linkhere"><p class="circletext">Some text</p></a></div>
```

My js:

```
if ($('.circletext').is(':empty')){
$('.sticker').hide();
} else { 
$('.sticker').show();
}
```

Would appreciate any help :) Cheers

Comment: var arr =$('.circletext:empty');
$.each(arr,function(i,v){
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly only select the empty `p`s then only hide the `div`s they are in.

```
$('.circletext').filter(':empty').closest('.sticker').hide();
```